# Add the last payment date to tree view for account.invoices

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, saas

I need to add the last payment date to the tree view for account.invoices. I am wondering how I can reference the date in payments through the payment_ids.. I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

To be clear, I need to do it through the tree-view editor as I'm using the SAAS version.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to create fields.function means compute field in account invoice for the last payment date and in that compute field you need to find the last payment from payment_ids and set in that compute field.

Comment: Not really fields.function because its odoo 9, but is a computed field that is the same idea

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I do appreciate it! Would you possibly be able to supply an example or maybe a link to documentation, please? I'm not able to find anything that makes sense to me as far as doing all of this in the tree view editor directly.